# check before insert

Tags: sql

i have this problem with inserting value that check the data from the table before it inserting .

here is a table

---

```
| ID | activity | event |
_________________________
| 1  | basket   | event1|
_________________________
| 2  | valley   | event1|
_________________________
```

is it possible to check activity and event before it insert?
example
i could insert 'basket' 'event2'
error if i insert 'basket' 'event1'
can someone help meg or any idea to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a unique constraint on the `activity` and `event` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD CONSTRAINT uc UNIQUE (activity, event)
```

Then, if someone tried to insert a combination of `activity`/`event` values which already exist, e.g. ('basket', 'event1'), the database would throw an error.

Comment: i tried to make the activity as unique but i don't let me add same value in activity but different value in event

Comment: will it work if i try to insert ('basket', 'event2')??

Comment: i will give a shot with that :) @Tim